# How do I cycle in "pyautogui" and write each number in the cycle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

I'd like to write a cycle that'd write:

```
data1, data2, data3, data(n)
```

Here is my python code:

```
import pyautogui
for i in 2:
pyautogui.typewrite("data"$i"")
```

Thank you.

```
import pyautogui
for i in range(1, 5):
    pyautogui.click(476, 679) 
    pyautogui.click(clicks=3) 
    pyautogui.typewrite(['delete']) 
    value = -0.5 + (i - 1) * 0.00001 
    pyautogui.typewrite("value")  
    pyautogui.typewrite(['enter'])
    pyautogui.click(169, 681) 
    pyautogui.click(330, 685) 
    pyautogui.click(448, 174) 
    pyautogui.typewrite("data{}".format(i))
    pyautogui.click(978, 664)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have several syntax errors in your code and you're not using the `for` loop correctly.

In order of occurrence:

1. the `i` variable is a value not an index, to get an index you need to use the [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#enumerate) function
2. the number `2` isn't a [valid variable name](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names), try changing it to: `two`
3. there is no `$` formatting in python, use the [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html) method instead

Here, try replacing your code with this:

```
import pyautogui

for i in range(1, 5):
  pyautogui.typewrite("data{}".format(i))
```

**NOTE:** I don't mean to sound rude but I'd suggest checking out [Sentdex's Python3 basics series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oVp1vrfL_w4&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDe8XSftW-RAxdo6OmaeL85M), which is what I used to get started with Python.

**UPDATE:** to get a range of numbers (without having to type each number manually) use the [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#func-range) function instead.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you. I get an error `NameError: name 'two' is not defined`

Comment: @LukášAltman I've updated my answer, let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you I added whole my code to my question. Is there any mistake please? It doesn't write numbers to required field, only the first one.

Comment: @LukášAltman Don't add different code to the same question, ask a different question.

Answer (score 1):

Great question,

> Firstly make sure you have all dependencies installed for your OS. 
>   find out more [here](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#purpose)

```
pip3 install pyautogui
```

open terminal and run :

```
python3

import pyautogui
for i in range(0, 10):
    pyautogui.typewrite("data%d, " % i)
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thank zou and what mean `module 'klikatko' has no attribute '__path__')` ?

Comment: make sure python3 is in your `$PATH`